# Can I test tesseract ocr in windows command line?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am new to tesseract OCR. I tried to convert an image to tif and run it to see what the output from tesseract using cmd in windows, but I couldn't. Can you help me? What will be command to use?

Here is my sample image:

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you have tried in more detail.

Comment: @Vish I installed tesseract library from its site. and from cmd i tried to convert the text image. tesseract imagename.tif output. But couldn't get any output.

Comment: For the syntax you typed, the output is stored in a file, output.txt. Did you check that such a file was created? Also, can you upload your TIF File somewhere? If I get some time I can check with my tesseract install.

Comment: @Vish Now I have added the tif image

Comment: @Vish thanks a lot i found the solution. can you comment your email i need to get advisers from you

Comment: @Vish I am trying to recognize handwritten text . Do you think I can use tesseract? any other sollution

Comment: I have only used Tesseract; I deal with it only from the point-of-view of recognizing text on a mobile screen. No info on how to recognize handwriting, sorry.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simplest tesseract.exe syntax is `tesseract.exe inputimage output-text-file`.
The assumption here, is that tesseract.exe is added to the `PATH` environment variable.
You can add the `-psm N` argument if your text argument is particularly hard to recognize.

I see that the regular syntax (without any `-psm` switches) works fine enough with the image you attached, unless the level of accuracy is not good enough.

Note that non-english characters (such as the symbol next to prescription) are not recognized; my default installation only contains the English training data.

Here's the tesseract syntax description:

```
C:\Users\vish\Desktop>tesseract.exe
Usage:tesseract.exe imagename outputbase [-l lang] [-psm pagesegmode] [configfile...]

pagesegmode values are:
0 = Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
1 = Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
2 = Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR
3 = Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
4 = Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
5 = Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
6 = Assume a single uniform block of text.
7 = Treat the image as a single text line.
8 = Treat the image as a single word.
9 = Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
10 = Treat the image as a single character.
-l lang and/or -psm pagesegmode must occur before anyconfigfile.

Single options:
  -v --version: version info
  --list-langs: list available languages for tesseract engine
```

And here's the output for your image (NOTE: When I downloaded it, it converted to a PNG image):

```
C:\Users\vish\Desktop>tesseract.exe ECL8R.png out.txt
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica

C:\Users\vish\Desktop>type out.txt.txt
1 Project Background

A prescription (R) is a written order by a physician or medical doctor to a pharmacist in the form of
medication instructions for an individual patient. You can't get prescription medicines unless someone
with authority prescribes them. Usually, this means a written prescription from your doctor. Dentists,

optometrists, midwives and nurse practitioners may also be authorized to prescribe medicines for you.

It can also be defined as an order to take certain medications.

A prescription has legal implications; this means the prescriber must assume his responsibility for the
clinical care ofthe patient.

Recently, the term "prescriptionΓÇ¥ has known a wider usage being used for clinical assessments,
```

Comment: Can you give me example of how to use configfile?