# Python OCR Tesseract cannot recognize Single Characters

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I have two TIF images. First Image(a.tif) is:

[image: Single Character Image]

and Second Image(bcd.tif) is

[image: Multiple Character Image]

When I am using ***"tesseract a.tif a.txt"*** it is not reading that Character and The same command ***"tesseract bcd.tif bcd.txt"*** is working.I have seen some answers in stackoverflow they they didn't gave solution how to run that.If we need to add any parameters what are those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue has something to do with there being only a single character in the image. For instance I tried these two images:

This one works fine. Tesseract reports 95% confidence in the result:

[image]

This one doesn't work.

[image]

I also tried scanning that image with PageSegMode set to SingleChar, and then it is scanned fine.

The command line argument for that should be `-psm 10`. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26418458/5894241

Answer (score 3):

as you said you need to change the mode to single character mode, you can do that in python by using the following command

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img_path , config="--psm 10")
```